# Why can't numpy remove this useless dimension?

Tags: python, numpy

No matter what I do to this array:

```
data = np.mean(np.mat(segment_data), axis=0)
print(data)
print(data.shape)
print(data[0].shape)
print(data[0,:].shape)
print(data.squeeze().shape)
print(data.flatten().shape)
print(data.transpose().shape)
print(data.transpose()[:,0].shape)
```

The output is still two-dimensional:

```
[[-0.48134436 13.09216948 10.63232405 10.6977263  11.95639315 13.83434023
  13.61501793  8.21932062  8.93592935 26.15871746 58.73205665]]
(1, 11)
(1, 11)
(1, 11)
(1, 11)
(1, 11)
(11, 1)
(11, 1)
```

What is happening? Why does numpy refuse to give me a 1-dimensional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specifically used `numpy.matrix`, which refuses to be 1-dimensional. Don't use `numpy.matrix`! Remove that `np.mat` call.

Comment: `segment_data` is 2D, its `data` that I need to flatten

Comment: @Luke: `data` is a matrix because it was created by taking the mean of a matrix. Just stop using `numpy.matrix`. It's terrible, it has all sorts of weird incompatibilities, it's the direct cause of your problem, and its only use case went away years ago when they added the `@` operator.

Comment: Importantly, you should use `numpy.array` instead.